# Emacs TAGS file in Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, ctags

One way to look into the source code of any function in Emacs is to use the `M-.` (find tag). When I do this in Windows platform Emacs 24 I get `Find tag:` in the minibuffer asking to enter the name of a function like for example, `forward-paragraph` function I don't get any. It seems there is no TAGS file there. When I wanted to create one, using `M-x compile RET etags *.el RET`, of no avail. Can you pls help me figure out what is the right way to get TAGS file in Windows?

**Update**
I managed to make TAGS file in `c:\GNU Emacs 24.3\` from Windows Terminal: `etags -o c:\GNU Emacs 24.3\TAGS c:/GNU Emacs 24.3/lisp/*.el`. After some googling, and the `-o` option is to tell where to write the generated TAGS file (destination). But, first as nanny pointed out, this should be run where `etags.exe` file resides. So I ran this from the `c:\GNU Emacs 24.3\bin\`. My questions:

- Where to put the TAGS file, what is the best practice?
- Why pressing `M-.`: find tag, then asks about table tags and I should point out to same dir where TAGS is, that is too much, how to make emacs automatically recognize TAGS?
- Even after finding TAGS by emacs, the function `forward-paragraph` was not among the  completion items? How to cover all `.el` files given a default dir structure of Emacs in Windows platform?
- I found beside `etags`  there is `exuberant ctags`, which one is better in Windows?

Comment: What do you mean "of no avail"? What happens? Any errors?

Comment: I still cannot use the find-tag.

Comment: You need to be more description of your problem. Why can't you use `find-tag`? Does running the command do nothing? Is it giving you an error? Is it telling you to select a tags table? Or what?

Comment: I updated the post, pls don't make any assumptions, I am new to Emcas.

Comment: I suggest trying the Windows port of [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) (run it with the `-e` argument to get Emacs-compatible output) which (a) tends to be better than the GNU etags binary, and (b) can do recursive processing on its own (with the `-R` argument), without you needing to use `find` (which is another pitfall on Windows) to walk the directory tree.

Comment: @phils, since recursive it must be what I am looking for. pls can you upgrade your comment to an answer? I have not a folder `ctags58` has many files in it, certainly with `ctags58.exe`. how to go from there?

Comment: after successfully generating TAGS file using the exuberant ctags from the terminal, I got this error to find `regexp` function: `File c:/emacs/lisp/wid-edit.el (with or without extensions ( .Z .bz2 .gz .xz .tgz)) not found` any idea? but I noticed that my folder is `c:/GNU Emacs 24.3/lisp/...` not `c:/emacs/lisp/..`

Answer (score 2):

etags can't find any `*.el` files because there are none in the directory that you ran it in (see, the compile command says: `default-directory "~/"`). etags is not recursive. If you'd like it to be, you need to pass it file names like this:

```
dir /b /s *.el | etags
```

Or on Unix-like systems/with `find`:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.el" | xargs etags --append
```

See also: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags

Comment: in using terminal: I got this message: `c:\GNU Emacs 24.3> dir /b /s *.el | etags
 dir /b /s *.el | etags
'etags' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I've just noticed that you skipped the `compile` command, right?

Comment: You can put it in your compile command. But first, you have to figure out in which directory all these *.el are in. Then, use the `dir` command in that directory. Like: `dir /b /s /path/to/emacs/src/*.el` For instance using my Emacs source directory, the command would be: `dir /b /s C:\Users\nanny\emacs-25.0.50-windows-x64\share\emacs\25.0.50\lisp\*.el | etags`.

Comment: Compile just runs a shell command. You can use this `dir ... | etags` in `compile` if you want. This will generate a `TAGS` file in the directory you pass to `dir`.

Comment: The reason you got `'etags' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` is because `etags` is not in your PATH. You'll need to add it to your path (use Google) or specify the full file path to etags.exe. In your case I assume it would be `C:\GNU Emacs 24.3\bin\etags.exe`.

Comment: I put this in the compile command: ` dir /b /s C:\GNU Emacs 24.3 \*.el | etags`. and etags.exe was in there. I got: `-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/" -*-
Compilation started at Mon Nov 10 22:01:22

dir /b /s C:\GNU Emacs 24.3\*.el | etags
The system cannot find the file specified.
etags: no input files specified.
 Try `etags --help' for a complete list of options.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Nov 10 22:01:23`

Comment: will this go in deeper dir levels?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18542/discussion-between-doctorate-and-nanny).

Comment: I have to go now, we continue tomorrow, thanks a lot.

Comment: can u pls have a look at the update?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Cygwin, just download [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and compiled then install it; or install via Cygwin installer. Then, you can simply run:

```
ctags -e -R
```

At your project root to generate Emacs-compatible TAGS file for your project.

Comment: ok, I have a problem after tag-find: whatever function entered after completion, it returns this message: `File c:/emacs/lisp/button.el (with or without extensions ( .Z .bz2 .gz .xz .tgz)) not found` how to fix?

Comment: Your Emacs is missing that file. I suggest you use [this 64 bit Windows build](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/).